# Does declare-function recognize functions declared via cl-defun?

Tags: declare, cl

It seems that `declare-function` + `check-declare-file` do not recognize functions defined via `cl-defun`.

I was happy using `declare-function` because it comes with `check-declare-file` that actually checks whether the declaration is consistent with the actual code in some other source file. However, when I upgraded the code for one of my declared functions, adding some keyword arguments and relying on `cl-defun` for handling them, `check-declare-file` could not validate and said that the function was not to be found.

Is there a workaround I could use? Or maybe `declare-function` is obsolete and there is some newer method I should use instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact error message. In what context did you encounter it?

Comment: @NickD. My initial description was quite confused. The error occurs when using `check-declare-file`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first note that [`check-declare-verify`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/a0b18d3cc22331a7c30520d654a85330a9557e6e/lisp/emacs-lisp/check-declare.el#L151) actually has a pattern for `cl-defun` in its regexp. So it should work.

If it does not maybe you should double-check and report an error if your code is not the source of the problem.

If it really turns out that you did not make any error and want to suppress the warning the [doc string for `declare-function`](https://gitlab.com/basil-conto/emacs/-/blob/f9daa69547f1e91c9dabdf6b47b00e95e11c51e0/lisp/subr.el#L50-53) answers your question:

> `(declare-function FN FILE &optional ARGLIST FILEONLY)`
>
> …
>
> Optional `FILEONLY` non-nil means that `check-declare` will check
> only that `FILE` exists, not that it defines `FN`.  This is intended
> for function definitions that `check-declare` does not recognize,
> e.g., `defstruct`.

So use a non-nil `FILEONLY` argument in `check-declare` for functions defined by `cl-defun`.